# SQLDataReader GetDateTime Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Check my code below:

HTML Page:

```
<table width="100%" align="right" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" bgcolor="#EAEAEA">
    <tr align="center" style="background-color: yellow; color: black;">
        <th colspan="2">Fauzan</th>
        <th colspan="2">Febri</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left" style="background-color: gray; color: black;">
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Number01</td>
        <td>TheDate</td>
        <td>Number02</td>
    </tr>
    <%=getWhileLoopData()%>
</table>
```

Code Behind:

```
public string getWhileLoopData() 
{
 string htmlStr = "";
 SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
 SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
 thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE TheDate = @TheDate";
 thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TheDate", txtDate.Text);

 thisConnection.Open();
 SqlDataReader reader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();

 while (reader.Read()) {
     int id = reader.GetInt32(0);

     int Number01 = reader.GetInt32(1);
     DateTime TheDate = reader.GetDateTime(2);
     Decimal Number02 = reader.GetDecimal(3);

     //string Pass = reader.GetString(2);
     htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + Number01 + "</td><td>" + TheDate + "</td><td>" + Number02 + "</td></tr>";
 }

 thisConnection.Close();
 return htmlStr;
}
```

The question is, how can i format the data reader? Like, "TheDate" field, from '6/18/2014 12:00:00 AM' to '18/Jun/2014'. Also for 'Number02' field, how can i format it? Like, from '0.829' become '0.83'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format datetime using ToString() with [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string strDate = TheDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
```

You can use [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to format number

```
Number02 = Math.Round(Number02, 2);
```

You can directly format date and number in the html string you are making

```
htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + Number01 + "</td><td>" +
   TheDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") + "</td><td>" +  Math.Round(Number02, 2) + "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Hey mate, it works! Thank you so much. Also another one, how can i format number? Like, From 1200 to 1,200. Want to use comma as a separator. And probably want also to put .00 after the number. Cheers,

Comment: You can use something like, String.Format("{0:n2}", 1234)

Comment: Hey mate, from my question above.. How can i put the total of Number 02 on html table?