# Average without calculate zero C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Refer to this link: [Standard HTML table with total from SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625255/standard-html-table-with-total-from-sql-server-table)

How can I skip zero value, when running the "Average" records?
Example:

```
ID     Number01     TheDate     Number02
----------------------------------------
1      10           01/06/2014  5
2      20           02/06/2014  0
3      30           03/06/2014  15
4      50           04/06/2014  60
5      0            05/06/2014  0
6      0            06/06/2014  0
7      0            07/06/2014  0
TOTAL  110          -           80
AVE    27.50        -           26.67
```

Check on the above table. 
'Number01' field, If I run the average formula for all records. The average is 15.71 but if I skip the zero values, the average is 27.50. Also for 'Number02' field.

This is my Code behind:

```
int totnum1 = 0;
decimal totnum2 = 0;
int numRow = 0;
decimal avg1 = 0;
decimal avg2 = 0;

totnum1 += reader.GetInt32(1);
totnum2 += reader.GetInt32(3);
numRow ++;

avg1 = totnum1 / numRow;
avg2 = totnum2 / numRow;

public string getWhileLoopData() {
    string htmlStr = "";
    SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
    thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE TheDate = @TheDate";
    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TheDate", txtDate.Text);

    int totnum1 = 0;
    decimal totnum2 = 0;
    int numRow = 0;
    decimal avg1 = 0;
    decimal avg2 = 0;

    thisConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read()) {
        int id = reader.GetInt32(0);

        int Number01 = reader.GetInt32(1);
        DateTime TheDate = reader.GetDateTime(2);
        Decimal Number02 = reader.GetDecimal(3);

        totnum1 += reader.GetInt32(1);
        totnum2 += reader.GetInt32(3);
        numRow ++;

        //string Pass = reader.GetString(2);
        htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + Number01 + "</td><td>" + TheDate + "</td><td>" + Number02 + "</td></tr>";
    }

    thisConnection.Close();

    avg1 = totnum1 / numRow;
    avg2 = totnum2 / numRow;

    htmlStr += string.Format("<tfoot><tr><td>Tot</td><td>{0}</td><td></td><td>{1}</td></tr>", totnum1 , totnum2 );
    htmlStr += string.Format("<tfoot><tr><td>Avg</td><td>{0}</td><td></td><td>{1}</td></tr></tfoot>", avg1 , avg2 );
    return htmlStr;
}
```

Comment: You use a WHERE clause in your SQL.

Comment: Average=SUM/N. You need to count how many values are different from zero. So for your request Average=SUM(Values)/SUM( Value<>0 )

Comment: @nvoigt... yes... I retracted my comment after re-reading the question... good call

Comment: Please ask self-contained questions, it's pretty hard to answer something that needs link-hopping over at least two other posts.

Comment: @nvoigt, "Please ask self-contained questions", I didn't get you mate.

Comment: I mean you should ask a question that can be answered by reading your post here. Not following links that assume you follow another link.

Comment: @nvoigt, I did. But no one answer, check the latest comment on the reference link.

Comment: I don't want to check reference links. Ask a question here. Right here. A fully fledged, self-contained, good question. Refer to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need advice on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give you exact code without knowing your data structure, but assuming you're looking for C# code, LINQ will do this nicely. Otherwise, a `WHERE` in SQL would. I would pick between them based on a few things, but mostly whether you need to pull the data down anyway. So for instance, if you're printing out a table with a totals row, I'd use the LINQ solution. But if you're just looking for the average to display on itself, use `WHERE`.

```
int[] args = new int[] { 0, 10, 25, 0, 70 };

return args.Where(c => c != 0).Average();
```

**Edit:**

Looking at the link as you requested, I would just add a `List<int>` to store all the values, then run this query against that. That isn't the most efficient solution, but I don't get the impression that efficiency is more important here than readability, and the difference won't really be noticeable if you have very few records.

Comment: mmm... don't think he wants a LINQ solution. He chose `sql` tag but not `linq` tag.

Comment: Please open the reference link, I am using the same code. But need to know, how to skip the zero values.

Comment: @Haminteu I've edited my answer, but basically I'd just add in a `List<int>`, and on each iteration through your `SqlDataReader` add your value to that. Then you can call the code I gave you here against that `List<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out the zeroes before you build the average... well, you have to filter out the zeroes, before you build your average:

```
SELECT AVG(Value)
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  Value <> 0
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please check the reference link? I am using the same code. Just need to know, how to filter the zero value in average section. Cheers.

Comment: @Haminteu You can add a basic counter there, counting only those rows that are not zero. There is a wide gap between what you want to do, using SQL and C# and what you can do. Maybe sitting back and reading a good basic book first will get you to your target faster than copy-pasting stuff from SO without understanding how it works.

Comment: Thank you.. Is it hard to help others if you can?

Comment: It's not hard, but it's useless. Some day I may have to work with you and I'd prefer somebody who learned the basics properly, not somebody who copied them from SO without understanding them. Make sure you *understand* the answer that was given because if you do,  modifying it for your needs should not be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Went through the post you have linked. What you need to do is to change the following lines:

```
totnum1 += reader.GetInt32(1);
totnum2 += reader.GetInt32(3);
numRow ++;
```

to this:

```
totnum1 += Number01;
totnum2 += Number02;
if(Number01 != 0 || Number02 != 0) numRow ++;
```

`numRow` will only increment if the corresponding column in the current row is not zero, thus the denom of your Avg expression will only count non-zero rows.

Comment: Where in his post does he say he's grouping?

Comment: @nvoigt: Good point. Looking at the result set, it appears he's grouping. But I agree that it could be a simple result too, hence I edited and added `WHERE` suggestion.